# Sticky header always visible?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm using a WordPress Plugin called "Sticky header by Thematosoup" and I'm very happy with it but the header only appears after some pixels and is not always visible on top. Does anyone know how I can modificate the code to make it always visible?

[Here's the website with the header I'm talking about](http://rosaegg.at/entwurf/)

Comment: site link is not working. Can you proper it?

Comment: Sorry: http://rosaegg.at/entwurf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the plugin is overriding the css that's why it's causing the issue.
You need to edit the css as the following :

```
#thsp-sticky-header {
   margin-top:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Please also upvote the answer if you find it helpful!! It will be delicious!! Thanks.